# Count number of rows in a different Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

It is in the same workbook. I have a few numbers in a range in Sheet3 and the button is in Sheet2. I want it to count the number of rows and then return the value to me in a msgbox. If I run this with the Sheet3 open it runs fine. If I run it with a different sheet active I get an object error for the counting part. It does insert the 3 in cell A2 no matter what sheet is active.

```
Sub problem3run()
Dim rngtest As Range

Set rngtest = Sheet3.Range("A2")

rngtest.Value = 3

Dim rngacount As Integer
rngacount = Sheet3.Range(Range("A4"), Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

MsgBox (rngacount)

End Sub
```

What is messed up in this?

Comment: Where do you define `Sheet3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues here. The first is that data type `Integer` can't hold all the rows in certain excel files, so you'll want to use `Long` instead. The second is that you are defining `rngacount` with unqualified `range` objects. Try this:

```
Sub problem3run()
Dim rngtest As Range

Set rngtest = Sheet3.Range("A2")

rngtest.Value = 3

Dim rngacount As Long '<~ use Long here rather than Integer
With Sheet3 '<~ use a With here to qualify ranges
    rngacount = .Range(.Range("A4"), .Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End With

MsgBox (rngacount)

End Sub
```

Comment: You need a '.' before the first Range also.

Comment: Great eye @LanceRoberts, I have updated the response above to qualify the first `range` object too. Thanks!