# Count the number of rows in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, with-statement

I have looked at the suggested questions to find the answer to my problem.
The closest question is called:
Count number of rows in a different Excel Sheet
[Count number of rows in a different Excel Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523674/count-number-of-rows-in-a-different-excel-sheet)

The solution to that problem does not work for me.

I am trying to count the number of rows in a range in a different worksheet than the active worksheet.
Here is my code:

```
Sub verbflashcards()

Dim wordcount As Long

With Worksheets("Verbs")
wordcount = .Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End With

MsgBox (wordcount)
End Sub
```

I have a worksheet called Verbs and it is the second worksheet in the workbook. I have tried:

```
With Verbs
With Sheet2
With Sheets("Verbs")
With Sheets("Sheet2")
```

None of them seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this and hope this will help you:

```
Sub verbflashcards()

Dim wordcount As Long

wordcount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Verbs").Range("A4", Worksheets("Verbs").Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

MsgBox (wordcount)

End Sub
```

Where, **D1** is the column from which you can get row count.

**Method 2:**

```
Sub verbflashcards()

Dim wordcount As Long
With Sheets("Verbs")
    wordcount = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

MsgBox (wordcount)
End Sub
```

Note: There are lots of answers to your questions. Check this SO link: [How can I find last row that contains data in the Excel sheet with a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro)

Comment: It works! So worksheets has to be referenced a second time inside the range?

Comment: There are couple of methods available to achieve the same., you can choose any one. Check my edited answer.

Comment: I think `.Range("D1"...` was intended to be `.Range("A4"...`. It seems you transposed the *r* and *c* from `Cells(4, 1)`.

Comment: That is not necessarily the number of used rows - it is the last row with data in column A (A1 could be blank etc).

Answer (score 14):

Your original was not working because the parent of `Cells(4, 1)` and `Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown)` was not specified. Prefix any cell address with a period (aka . or *full stop*) when you are inside a `With ... End With` block. Example:

```
With Worksheets("Verbs")
  wordcount = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End With
```

Note the `.Cells(4, 1)` and not `Cells(4, 1)`. The period specifies that the cell(s) you are referring to are within Worksheets("Verbs").

Comment: YES, You are exactly right!!! You have to be careful when you are using WITH block.