# Run-time error '1004' while copying

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the infamous Run-time error when I run this code, and I don't understand why:

`With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    .Range(Cells(row1, column1), Cells(row2, column1)).Copy
 End With`

row1, column1 and row2 are all defined as Integers.

The error pops up for the second line of code.

Can I get some insight please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the "." before `Cells` (as you are within the `With` scope of the Sheet Data)

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Copy
End With
```

Tested the above example and now it works for me.

Comment: Good catch. I dealt with a very similar situation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763089/count-the-number-of-rows-in-another-sheet/27763394#27763394).

Comment: Thanks :). Quite a common error of my own actually. Too bad Excel does not generate more understandable error messages....

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! It's the first time I use the "With...End with", so I wasn't too sure of the syntax.

Comment: Great to hear that. Please mark as answer to close thread then

Answer (score 0):

Where are you coping the range to.  The proper format is

source.copy destination

```
Sheets("Count").Range("C2:D3").Copy Sheets("Count").Range("E2:F3")
```