# Excel VBA run time error 1004 on Range object

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Trying to count whether or not something is present within a grid in excel thats defined by whether or not it is filled with a color or not (thats how my boss wants it formatted). Not really an expert at VBA, and am getting an error in the second line of this loop. Variables are defined before this, and theres a bunch of other stuff inside the loop, but I'm not including that to save space. I'm pretty sure the problem would be evident here.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Core List")
Do While Not .Range(Cells(3, x)).Value = ""    'while current name box isn't empty

    name1 = .Range(Cells(3, x)).Value       'sets the name in the stat sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(stat).Range(Cells(4, x - 2)) = name1

Loop
End With
```

Comment: Is stat a variable ? or a name of a sheet ? Also you might need to simply add  .Value to the end of that line

Comment: Need to know what you've declared your variables are, how you're setting them and what line the error is occurring on.

Comment: See [Run-time error '1004' while copying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251910/run-time-error-1004-while-copying/31251977) from yesterday.

Comment: Is your clipboard fill when you are attempting the count? If so, It may help to count before you are attempting a copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sheet where the code is in is not the same as "Core List", you just need to use `.Cells`, see:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Core List")
    Do While Not .Cells(3, x).Value = ""    'while current name box isn't empty

        name1 = .Cells(3, x).Value       'sets the name in the stat sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(stat).Cells(4, x - 2).Value = name1

    Loop
End With
```

1 - You don't need to put `Cells` inside `Range` if you want only one cell. And if you use `Cells` loose like that, it will take the cell from the sheet where you inserted this code. But if you use `.Cells`, you take it from the sheet you declared in the `With` block.

**Notice**: if `x` is zero or lower, it will fail, there is no column 0 in a sheet. Also, if it's too big (I believe 256), you will too blow the limits of the sheet.

Comment: Thanks! The .Cells thing fixed it.