# VBA: Subscript out of range error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still pretty new with VBA, and keep getting the subscript out of range error. I am trying to write code that reads data from one excel tab ("ip") and writes some of that data to another tab ("rtf"). When the ip tab has duplicate values for the variable ipIPCMP then I want to add a new row below the active row in my second tab rtf. The error occurs at the else part of the conditional statement. Thank you.

UPDATE: changed else to elseif and changed the with statement. Still get subscript out of range.

```
For i = 1 To n   

connectIPCMP = iPCMP(i)

    For j = 1 To m

    ipIPCMP = Sheets("ip").Cells(j + 1, 2)

        If ipIPCMP = connectIPCMP And k = 1 Then

            supplierList = Sheets("ip").Cells(j, 3)

            Sheets("rft").Cells(3 + j, 4) = list
            k = k + 1

         ElseIf ipointIPCMP = connectIPCMP And k > 1 Then

             With Worksheets("rtf")

                .Range(.Cells(3 + i, 1), .Cells(3 + i, 8)).Activate
                .ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

             End With

            Sheets("rft").Cells(3 + j, 4) = supplierList

            k = k + 1

        End If
    Next
```

Next

Comment: `Else: ipointIPCMP = connectIPCMP And k > 1` did you mean `elseif`?

Comment: Change `Else:` to `ElseIf` and add `Then` to the end of the line.

Comment: You just need `ElseIf`.  Using only `Else` means that when the `If` statement isn't next, no matter what, run what's after `Else`.  Using `ElseIf` will: When the `If` statement isn't met, look to the condition in `ElseIf` to see if that's met..if not, it will continue (in your case, to `End If`).

Comment: What are you trying to do with `addrow = ...`  The activate does not work with the `=`.  Are you trying to set a range, or is addrow an array?

Comment: I want to select a range (a row) and then add a row below that row.

Comment: The subscript out of range error is because you misspelled the sheet name.....With Worksheets("rtf") should be With Worksheets("rft") after the End With line.

Answer (score 3):

1. Change `Else:` to `ElseIf` and add `Then` to the end of the line.
2. Reference the range properly.

   ```
   With Worksheets("rtf")
        .Range(.Cells(3 + i, 1), .Cells(3 + i, 8)).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
   End with
   ```

Note `.Cells` and not `Cells`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763089/count-the-number-of-rows-in-another-sheet/27763394#27763394).

**Better Approach**

```
    For i = 1 To n
        connectIPCMP = iPCMP(i)
        With Worksheets("rtf")   '<~~CHECK THIS WORKSHEET NAME!!!!!
            For j = 1 To m
                ipIPCMP = Worksheets("ip").Cells(j + 1, 2)
                If ipIPCMP = connectIPCMP And k = 1 Then
                    supplierList = Sheets("ip").Cells(j, 3)
                    .Cells(3 + j, 4) = List
                    k = k + 1
                ElseIf ipointIPCMP = connectIPCMP And k > 1 Then
                    .Cells(3 + i, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert  '<~~only need a single cell if you are going to insert an entire row
                    .Cells(3 + j, 4) = supplierList
                    k = k + 1
                End If
            Next j
        End With
    Next i
```

The code sample you provided only tells half of the story but the above is the best I can offer without seeing the full story.

---

¹ <sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>

Comment: I changed the with statement now to your suggestion but it still gives me the same error there,
    With Worksheets("rtf")
                
                 addrow = Range(.Cells(3 + i, 1), .Cells(3 + i, 8)).Activate
                 
                End With

Comment: You cannot use the `=` and `.Activate` like that. `Range` should be `.Range`. Please see [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I adjusted the code accordingly but still get the same exact error. I have troubles understanding what should be included within the with statement. Can I include the activate statement in the with statement?

Comment: The short answer is Yes. The  long answer is Why would you want to? Relying on ActiveCell, Select, etc is unreliable at best and error-prone at worst.

Comment: btw, did you know that you are using `"rft"` in one place and `"rtf"` in another? Perhaps that is generating the confusion.

Comment: Good catch!  That changed the type of error. Now I get "Activate method of range class failed" error. (I should be able to figure this one out) You're definitely right that relying on this activate-thing is very error-prone. Thanks alot!