# VBA copy range error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I get a 1004 error when running this code:

```
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

Row = Worksheets("Design").Cells(11, 22).Value
Col = Worksheets("Design").Cells(12, 22).Value

Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Range(Cells(2 + 19 * Row, 1 + 19 * Col), Cells(19 + 19 * Row, 18 + Col * 19)).Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Scriptsheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(18, 18))
```

It point to the copy line, and I dunno what is wrong here. Thanks for you help

Comment: The `Cells()` inside the `Range()` are refering to the active sheet not the sheet to which the `Range()` is referring.  You need to qulaify the `Cells()` to the proper sheet. `Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Range(Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Cells(2 + 19 ...` and so on.

Comment: Like this: `code`Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Range(Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Range(Cells(2 + 19 * Row, 1 + 19 * Col), Cells(19 + 19 * Row, 18 + Col * 19))).Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Scriptsheet").Range(Worksheets("Scriptsheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(18, 18))) `code`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763089/count-the-number-of-rows-in-another-sheet/27763394#27763394

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Cells()` inside the `Range()` are referring to the active sheet not the sheet to which the `Range()` is referring.

You need to qualify the `Cells()` to the proper sheet.

```
Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Range(Worksheets("Tablecorrected").Cells(2 + 19 ... and so on.
```

Or to save typing you would use a With Block

```
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

Row = Worksheets("Design").Cells(11, 22).Value
Col = Worksheets("Design").Cells(12, 22).Value

With Worksheets("Tablecorrected")

    .Range(.Cells(2 + 19 * Row, 1 + 19 * Col), .Cells(19 + 19 * Row, 18 + Col * 19)).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Scriptsheet").Range(Worksheets("Scriptsheet").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("Scriptsheet").Cells(18, 18))

End With
```