# VBA Syntax on Match Method

Tags: vba, excel

```
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(51187, Sheets("New Master Data 6.1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells((Rows.Count), 1)), 0)
```

I cant find whats wrong with my syntax.  Help please :)

Comment: Close duplicate of [Count the number of rows in another sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763089/count-the-number-of-rows-in-another-sheet/27763394#27763394).

Answer (score 2):

If "New Master Data 6.1" is not the active sheet then your code will error, because in a regular code module any instance of `Cells()` without a qualifying worksheet will refer to the active sheet.

I would use something like:

```
With Sheets("New Master Data 6.1")
    y = Application.Match(51187, .Columns(1), 0)
End with

If Not IsError(y) Then
    'do something with y
Else
    'value was not found
End If
```

Note that dropping the `WorksheetFunction` allows you to test the return value, instead of triggering a run-time error when there's no match.

Comment: Note that y cannot be a Long; it must be a variant to catch the error